# How to get values from firebase db

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, angularfire2

I cant understand how to get values from db firebase

Using Angular 8+, Realtime Database. 
Structure of DB: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Mt3.png)

```
urls: string[];
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}
```

I need to get array with urls (values) from db. Can someone help? Please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable,FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';



 photos:FirebaseListObservable<any>;
 constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.photos= db.list('Photos');
          }
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let photo of photos| async">
       {{ photo | json }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: you might be using different angularfire package
import { AngularFireObject, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

use AngularFireObject not FirebaseObjectObservable and AngularFireList not FirebaseListObservable

Comment: Yeah, i know, but i try to this too. Catch another error ```MainContentComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.```

Comment: just try this in html <li>{{photos | json}} </li>

Comment: what is it? you are getting result or not?

Comment: no. i get link to db (db.firebase.com/photos) but i need to get links from db like on screen in topic 'Structure of DB'

Comment: But list should display everything inside the db

Comment: Check this sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-crud-example-jwtegb?file=src/app/services/people.service.ts

Comment: ```photos: AngularFireList<any>;
  constructor(private fb: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.photos = fb.list('/Photos')
  }```

Comment: Check the sample  in my previous comment